# How to prove $\lim _{n \to \infty} S_n=\infty$ for partial sums of a divergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ diverges and $a_n\geq 0 $, then

$\lim _{n \to \infty} S_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k =\infty $

Sol :
If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $diverges

Then,

$ \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \not=0$

I don't know how complete  it, any hint or note for prove this problem .

Comment: Since $a_n\geq 0$, $S_n$ increases and must either diverge to $\infty$ or have a finite limit.

Comment: Same applies  to \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k |=\infty $?

Comment: The beginning of your solution is incorrect: that $\;\sum a_n\;$ diverges does **not** mean $\;\lim a_n\neq0\;$ ...Remember the harmonic series, say.

Comment: @DonAntonio After prove the s_n increasing, how to prove it unbounded ? To prove s_n goes to infinite

Comment: @user508518 As Gabriel mentioned, you get the sum of **positive** sereis and thus the sequence of partial sums is monotonic ascending, and it converges iff that sequence is bounded from above. Otherwise it diverges to infity. Each case is different...

Answer (score 0):

$a_n\ge 0$, then $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is a increasing sequence.

Therefore, $\lim_nS_n\ge0$ (possibly $\infty$)

If $\lim_nS_n\lt\infty$, then by definition of series, the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is said to be convergent, i.e., doesn't diverges.

Also, the solution you gave is wrong, as you can consider $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}=+\infty$ but $\lim_k\frac{1}{k}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The non-negativity of the sequence $(a_n)$ implies that $(S_n)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence since $S_{n+1}-S_n = a_{n+1} \geq 0$ for each $n$.

So, monotone convergence implies that there exists some extended real number (extended real number being either a real number or infinity) $x$ such that $(S_n)$ converges to $x$.

If $x \in [0, \infty)$ then $(S_n)$ is a convergent sequence and the series is convergent contrary to assumption. So, $x$ must be the extended real number $\infty$ which is to say that $(S_n)$ “diverges to infinity.”

Your book might not consider extended real numbers with the theorem on monotone convergence but adjusting for this shouldn’t be difficult.